# How can I permit a user to run some commands with passwordless sudo - without breaking all other commands?

Tags: linux, redhat, sudo

I am on a CIS-hardened RHEL 8 host on an AWS EC2 instance. My goal is to permit my user to run some commands with `sudo` passwordless (e.g. `ls`, `cat`, ...), while other commands (like `vi`) should stay password-protected.

I have added the following line to `/etc/sudoers.d/99-foo`, which is being included by `/etc/sudoers`:

```
myuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/visudo,/usr/bin/ls
```

(I have just locked myself out, hence the `visudo`...)

This works just fine for the specified commands:

```
[myuser@myhost ~]$ sudo ls -l /var/log/httpd/access_log | wc -l
1
```

However, all other commands - which I still want to work with password protection! - fail now:

```
[myuser@myhost ~]$ sudo echo "hello stackexchange!"
[sudo] password for myuser:
Sorry, user myuser is not allowed to execute '/bin/echo hello stackexchange!' as root on myhost.
```

Comment: What are the settings in /etc/sudoers ? Specifically, is wheel allowed to execute all commands? If so, is your user account in the wheel group?

Comment: Run `sudo -l` to see a list of commands that `sudo` thinks you have access to. If it's not listed in the output, you can't run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the rule that allows passwordless sudo for specific commands, you *also* need some other sudo rule which allows your user to run ALL commands with sudo.

The default sudo config allows users in the `wheel` group to run ALL commands with sudo (after supplying a password) and users who should have such access should be placed in this group.

```
# usermod -aG wheel myuser
```

If the user is logged in when added to a group, they must log out and log back in before this change takes effect.